# Can the DM inductors of an EMI filter be wound on the same core?

Tags: inductor, emc, emi-filtering, common-mode, toroidal

I want to implement the following EMI filter containing two separate LC filters such as DM and CM filters. Obviously, the CM inductors must be wound on the same core.

Can I also wind the DM inductors on the same core? (I don't mean all 4 inductors on the same core, I mean one core for CM inductors and one core for DM inductors.)
[image]

Comment: Draw dots on your magnetic components please.

Comment: @Andyaka I did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes possible. It is no harder to avoid saturation in a single core with two windings (your drawn scenario) than in two cores with one winding each. It all comes down to setting the core permeance and winding counts correctly to avoid saturation.

Winding the two differential mode inductors on the same core can be even beneficial, because you might need fewer turns.

Comment: really? how does it cause fewer windings?

Comment: @WeTech Say, to make a 1 mH inductor, you need 100 windings. If you take two of these 1 mH inductors you will have 200 windings total. If you wind both on a single larger core (with the same permeance), you want to produce a 20 mH total, so you need 100 * √2 = 141 windings. Because the core will be larger though, it can be that the wire length will be the same in the end (gut feeling).

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to avoid saturation of the core with the differential mode inductors as the flux does not cancel as it does with the common-mode inductors.

Comment: how about if we consider a bigger core to avoid saturation? is it technically possible to use only one core?

Comment: @WeTech - yes. Also an air gapped core can help.

Comment: as I want to use a toroidal core, applying an air gap is not possible. does adding a ferrite bar or plate shunt in the middle of the toroid help? (this is what Tim Williams recommended in the answer below)

Comment: @WeTech - Powdered iron has a distributed air gap and is more forgiving of saturation. If there is already a CM choke in the circuit is it necessary to have two DM chokes or will a single one do in the live side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Consider an E shaped core, with windings on the far legs.  Add an air gap to the middle leg.  Common mode (both windings reinforcing in the ungapped loop between far legs) will be very high inductance and low saturation current.  Differential mode (windings opposing, reinforcing through the center leg) will be low to modest inductance and saturation given by turns and air gap.

This could also be done with a toroid, adding a magnetic shunt in the middle and winding two sectoral windings (the way power CMCs are usually wound; as opposed to, like, a twisted pair winding).

Edit: to be clear, this means *a single core* can be used for both, if you like.  It requires specific geometry, so that one core can be used as two cores superimposed.  It may still be easier or cheaper to build with two independent cores.  Further decomposition (i.e. 3 cores, as 4 independent ones would lose CM as noted) has no effect, but may also be easier (i.e. single inductors are more commercially available than coupled ones).

Comment: what do you mean by "adding a magnetic shunt in the middle"? how is it possible to change the structure of a coated toroidal core?

Comment: @WeTech A magnetic shunt is a piece of magnetic material (i.e. a ferrite bar or plate in this case) which, well, shunts some of the magnetic flux around some path.