# What is the correct arrangement of the EMI filter?

Tags: inductor, emc, emi-filtering, power-factor-correction

I want to design an EMI filter for the input side of a PFC converter. there are various topologies for EMI filters. in some cases, the CM filter is located on the network side and the DM filter on the converter side. and in some other cases vice versa (CM filter on the converter side and DM filter on the network side). Which one is more suitable? Especially from the output impedance and stability point of view.

[image]

Comment: In what way is this DM filter separate from this CM filter? The combination together constitutes a network, which likely requires some adjustment of values for best results (vs. plugging two random things together and hoping for the best), in which case it's simply a filter network with some DM and CM attenuation in a given environment and order is ill defined if not completely irrelevant.

Comment: EMC is a holistic subject; even given total knowledge of your system (schematic, PCB layout, mech. assembly, layout and operating conditions during emissions test, etc.), your question may not have a clear answer. Needless to say, it doesn't provide nearly enough information as-is -- add as much of the above as you possibly can, and then we may be able to provide some insight.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not sure if the problem is with my local internet or the website's server, but the image can't be uploaded. The DM and CM stages are completely separate from each other, and their inductor and capacitor values are obtained according to relationships, and these two LC stages are placed one after the other in a cascade. If you look at the image attached to my previous question, you will see the topology, as I said, the order of stages has been changed in some topologies.

Comment: Ah yeah just saw that in another post, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382854/image-uploading-fails-with-failed-to-upload-image-an-error-occurred-on-the-ser try back later I guess.

Comment: The problem with cascading filters is that you've ignored leakage inductance of the CMC (referring to the previous post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/638177/can-the-dm-inductors-of-an-emi-filter-be-wound-on-the-same-core ). It will always necessarily have some DM function by itself -- and ignoring this can cause problems in the network overall (e.g. resonating with nearby capacitors causing a peak in the stopband). This is basically why you see big fat X caps flanking CMCs in most designs: to take advantage of it.

Comment: @TimWilliams Fortunately, the problem of uploading images has been solved and I have attached them. The leakage inductance of CMC is in the range of a few uH, which are added in series with DM inductances in the range of 100uH, on the other hand, the capacitor cx is placed near the CMC in both topologies. With these interpretations, can these leakage inductances be ignored? Do you have a solution to damp the resonance? In some topologies, I have seen that large resistors are used between the line and the neutral. How are the value and the correct position of these resistors determined?

Comment: Between the two configurations shown, in the top one, (Cy/2) * LL(CM) will have an unexpectedly high resonance, which could be damped by putting a Cx + ESR line-to-line at the Y caps., with ESR = sqrt(LL/(Cy/2)). Consider doing simulations, with a standard (usually 50 ohm) environment and compare topologies, component values, etc.